# How to pass null in a method?

Tags: dart

```dart
class Foo {
  final int? i;
  Foo({this.i});

  Foo copyWith({int? x}) {
    return Foo(i: x ?? i);
  }
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo(i: 0);

  foo.copyWith(x: null);
  print(foo.i); // prints `0` but should print `null`.
}
```

How can I actually pass `null` value to the method? In earlier Dart version `copyWith()` and `copyWith(x: null)` were two different things.

---

**Note:** I'm not looking for workarounds like making a new variable, like `isNull` and then deciding whether to pass `null` or not based on its value.

Comment: `return Foo(i: x ?? i);` This line means: if x is not null: take the value of x. and if it is null, take the value of i.So, i of the returned object is never updated if you pass null.
also, maybe you need to say `foo=foo.copyWith(x:null);` because you return a new object but never use it.

Comment: @MohamedAkram I knew what `x ?? i` means but the question is how do I pass `null` in such situations? Second, I used the conventional `ClassName copyWith` approach, but for the sake of this sample question, I didn't make use of returned `Foo` object.

Comment: Why don't you say `return Foo(i:x)`?

Comment: `Foo(i: x)` defeats the purpose of `copyWith` method. What if I didn't pass it any value and pass other variables some value?

Comment: `return Foo(i:x)` will return a new object with whatever value you pass, so it will update `i` to be null.

Comment: @MohamedAkram I am not sure how familiar you are with `Class copyWith` approach. You're simply defeating its purpose. I want to make both `copyWith()` and `copyWith(x: null)` to work differently.

Comment: You *did* successfully pass `null` to the `copyWith` method.  What `copyWith` chooses to do with the `null` argument is up to the `copyWith` implementation.  You probably want to see [Dart: Custom "copyWith" method with nullable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68009392/).

Comment: "In earlier Dart version `copyWith()` and `copyWith(x: null)` were two different things." That is still true, nothing has changed in that regard (yet!). What was the code that you had that worked in earlier Dart versions?

Comment: @lrn If they are still two different things then why did my code not work? This wasn't the code I used in earlier Dart version but I remember something like of sort worked.

Comment: My bad. They are still *not* different things, they're still the same, and always have been. (At least since long before Dart 1.0.)

Answer (score 1):

With simple `copyWith`whit Dart null-safety you can't override value by `null` because if `id` is `null` return `this.id`. You need to override the value by null but not return with another value. It can solve in a few ways but I will give you the best example.

```dart
void main() {
  final user = User(name: 'Dave', id: 110);

  User copy = user.copyWith(id: null);
  print(copy.toString()); // prints User(name: Dave, id: null).
}

class User {
  User({required this.name, this.id});

  final String name;
  final int? id;

  UserCopyWith get copyWith => _UserCopyWith(this);
  
  @override
  String toString() => 'User(name: $name, id: $id)';
}

abstract class UserCopyWith {
  User call({
    String name,
    int? id,
  });
}

class _UserCopyWith implements UserCopyWith {
  _UserCopyWith(this.value);

  final User value;
  static const _undefined = Object();

  @override
  User call({
    Object name = _undefined,
    Object? id = _undefined,
  }) {
    return User(
      name: name == _undefined ? value.name : name as String,
      id: id == _undefined ? value.id : id as int?,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this approach has a lot of boilerplate code. What if I have 20 such fields, the code will become way too long. But definitely a +1 for your efforts.

Comment: Every boilerplate code have a reason. Like this example you can override nullable value with null. I working with extension for vscode which will generate it with one click good alternative for them who don't like generators like Freezed :)

Comment: Check out [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71732563/12483095) of doing it. Much shorter

Comment: Yes I know this. I thought you want use pure copy with method. This shorter way depend on `Optional` type. My boilerplate code provide pure `copyWith(id: null);` But of course you can use `Optional` type.

Comment: There is no need to make `copyWith` a function object. Also `const Object()` is not unique, anyone can create that.
Consider an alternative like: https://gist.github.com/lrhn/c964ec4030ca7f9aefcd14162321f1ee 
It even works if the type of the field is `Object?` to begin with, as long as as the sentinel isn't leaked from the library. (Against `dart:mirrors`, no sentinel is safe).

Comment: I personally prefer clean code and easier readable. CopyWith call function like a guard does not allow overriding wrong type that, `const Object()` it safe to use here. And my code compared to yours is a few lines longer but not required abstract class. But anyway, if you feel comfortable with your code and without trouble that is ok :) I tried many different ways this one is the best one for me.

Comment: The `const Object` is safe to use here, as long as no-one casts the function to a sub-type accepting `Object?` (which the they only would if they *wanted* to circumvent the design, and then it's fine that things get odd). However, if your original class had a field with type `Object?`, you do need a sentinel in `copyWith` that users cannot create themselves by accident, and `const Object()` is not.
On which design is cleaner or more readable, we'll have to agree to disagree :)